# Add Series Dynamically by time Weekly,Monthly,Year,Years in echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have Line Chart like Below. so far so good.

[image: my eChart]

**Now i need to have a Drop Down which says Current Week,Current Month,Monthly,Year,Years**

Now i need to Change x-Axis/data/series Dynamically and Query data based on the Drop down from Database or is there a better way of doing this. I am just getting started with echarts.

If I select Current week, I should show Mon,Tue and so on... as Labels on x-Axis.
If I select CUrrent Month I should show Dates as Labels on x-Axis.
Same should happen with Year and Years.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the problem? Could you provide code example?

Anyway I see it like this:

1. In general, this is beyond the scope of the chart as chart component so place [select control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) into HTML like a regular tag `<select>`.
2. Add eventListener to the body and capture [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) with the selected option.
3. When received event and option send request to the backend or filter data locally by option value.
4. Then pack filtered data into chart object `{ series: { data: [...] }}`.
5. And call built-in chart method `chartInstance.setOption({ chart_object })` for update series.